# Problem with my apk on Android in Samsung

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build, apk

I am creating my mobile game, But I have a minor problem, I use unity 2018 and when I build my game and I have it as an apk file, I can't run it on my phone, I have the latest android and I wanted to ask if it can be an old version of unity. when I click on apk it tells me that an error occurred while checking the file. Porblem is only with samsung, on xiaomy I can normal play my game. Thank you.

Comment: Can you install it?  If so, when you run it what's the stack trace?  If not, what error occurs when you install it?  Right now we don't have any information to help you from

Comment: The first thought you should have in any WTF situation: " I need to check all available logs". In the case of the android devices, it is `logcat`.

Comment: When I click on apk it write "an error occurred while parsing the package". If is in game something wrong, it can´t run normal on xiaomy I think.

Answer (score 2):

We need more information about your problem
But in general, you can try to check the plugin inside the game, most of the errors that happen after build are caused either by plugin incompatibility or an xml file error

Comment: I don´t know what information I can give you, beacuse I don´t know more. I build my game in unity 2018. I set the targer to automatically the highest and installed the latest SDK with the help of android stuido. When I build my game, I move the apk file to the phone and on Xiaomy normal install and play the game and on Samsung I click on apk and it wrote error. I have samsung, my game normal work on it, but I update my phone, it delete my game and make this error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).